# Find Value and Use Value near it in EXCEL

Tags: excel

In excel I need to look up a number in one column and use the number next to it printing it to a different sheet.  For example the first number over 4000.  What is the best way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: Use the function Vlookup in the desired cell.

Comment: Use a `VLOOKUP`

Comment: vlookup, or if you want to use vba find the number((create a code) and print the next to it number using: offset(0,1)